# How to import XML Dataset to database of my Laravel project

Tags: angular, xml, laravel, api

I am working on a project with Angular as a frontend framework and Laravel as a backend framework, and they contact with each others using api requests.
the datasets for the project are on 12 XML files.

How can I import the XML files into Laravel database?

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a "one-time import by developer" I would do :

- Use software like "DBforge for MySQL" (paid with a trial, but there may be free software that does the same), it can import XML files, create the table schema for you, and import the data - this can also be done manually but can be longer depending on the XML complexity.
- In laravel, create a new dedicated service. Query the table using `Db::table()` helpers
- Code your way to import the XML, to your database schema, laravel models and relationships, etc.

If it's a useful feature import:

- there are packages like [this one](https://github.com/orchestral/parser) that can parse XML files.
- you need to develop the frontend to upload the file, and the PHP to check file format (column presence and names), and the logic to import (models, relationships...)

In both cases, if it should be done again after migration, for example, you can create seeders from it using a package like "iseeder" for laravel.

If the XML is contained exactly the data for your database, with everything like pivot table, relation ship foreigns, etc... You can just use dbforge to import columns to correct DB table columns, but I doubt the file have it all.